# How to put the input() in the middle of the sentence (python)?

Tags: python, input

I would like to get the input() in the middle of the sentence.

I have tried:

`print('I have ${} dollars'.format(float(input())))`

and get this:

```
45 #asked before showing the print
I have $45 dollars
```

instead of this:

```
I have $| dollars #(The "|" means the place where the input() is requested)
```

Is that possible?

Comment: You mean you want the user to be able to type their response in the middle of the sentence?

Comment: Sounds like you want a graphical interface rather than simple console IO.

Answer (score 1):

This is as close as you're going to get to what you want:

```
prefix = "I have $"
dollars = input(prefix)
ncols = len(dollars) + len(prefix) + 1
print(f"\033[F\033[{ncols}G dollars")
```

- `\033[F` go to the (start of the) previous line
- `\03[{ncols}G` move along ncols:

Comment: An interesting approach, though one that doesn't work on windows.